# how to mock json.parse() in jest tests

Tags: json, reactjs, parsing, jestjs

I have a try/catch in my code and when the code falls into the `catch` part it hits a JSON.parse()

```
catch(err){
    JSON.parse(err.message)
}
```

the code is working but the tests are failing. the test is just asserting something is happening in the try

```
try {
   popUp.method(mockedUrl)
}
```

the test is just asserting that this method was called but it's failing because something is blowing up in the `JSON.parse()` stage. just wondering how I can stub this out so that it knows what I've passed into the json?

Comment: you could refer to that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39193533/how-to-test-json-parse-in-jest

Comment: This is likely XY problem. Usually you need to mock data that is passed to JSON.parse, not JSON.parse itself.

Comment: @estus ok true. but when I log out `err` in the catch block, it's not even showing me anything. and when i `console.log('hello')` that shows. which confuses me. guess it has no idea what `err` is

Comment: @Xanax that is using sinon not jest

Comment: I'm not sure what your case is. Do you want to mock it for testing purposes or debugging purposes? Where do you log err and what the error can be to not be displayed? Is it an object at all? What purpose does `JSON.parse(err.message)` serve? It isn't doing anything. Please, post the code you're testing and your test, so you case could be more clear. You can mock JSON.parse as any other method but there's a chance this is wrong decision.

Comment: I need to mock out what gets passed into `JSON.parse(thisNeedsMocking)` because apparently there is an unexpected token in the json.  it's parsing my error message so that I can then do something with it later

Answer (score 22):

You could mock the JSON.parse implementation

```
JSON.parse = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
  // return your what your code is returning.
});
```

This should be enough once you shouldn't test the javascript built-in object: JSON. so you return what your code is expecting from it and the rest should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I'll post this as a second answer. For anyone who is using this in a suite of tests, this might be better:

```
jest.spyOn(JSON, 'parse').mockImplementationOnce(...)
```

JSON.parse is mocked only once this way. Doing

```
JSON.parse = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(...)
```

Makes it so that JSON.parse stays mocked after the first implementation is called.