# How can I test this function using Jest framework?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, xmlhttprequest

I have function below. I can't test this function using Jest framework.

The function:

```
const XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;



exports.xhrExample = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'url' , true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log('Some text');
            console.log('Some text');
        }
    };

    xhr.send(/*body*/);
}
```

The test:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
const { xhrExample } = require('../function/exampleXHR');

const open = jest.fn();
const setRequestHeader = jest.fn();
const send = jest.fn();
const status = 200;
const readyState = 4;

const xhrMockClass = function () {
        return {
        open,
        setRequestHeader,
        send,
        status,
        readyState
    };
};

global.XMLHttpRequest = jest.fn().mockImplementation(xhrMockClass);

test('Should make a request', () => {
    xhrExample();
})
```

In particular I can't cover if branch. How can I write the right test? I've seen many solutions but they don't work. I also used the xhr-mock utility but it still not working. Thanks to all.

Comment: Can't you mock json.parse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53228621/how-to-mock-json-parse-in-jest-tests/54656146?

Answer (score 0):

I will create an HTTP server to test it instead of mocking. Your code doesn't make sense, I did some refactoring and added `opts` parameters for `xhrExample` function. It's more generic and easier to test.

E.g.

`exampleXHR.js`:

```js
const XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;

exports.xhrExample = function (opts) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(opts.method, opts.url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      opts.onSuccess(response);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

`exampleXHR.test.js`:

```js
const http = require('http');
const { xhrExample } = require('./exampleXHR');

describe('71021143', () => {
  let server;
  beforeEach((done) => {
    server = http
      .createServer((req, res) => {
        const body = JSON.stringify({ name: 'amelia' });
        res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
        });
        res.write(body);
        res.end();
      })
      .listen(8000, done);
  });
  afterEach((done) => {
    server.close(done);
  });
  test('should pass', (done) => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    xhrExample({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:8000',
      onSuccess: (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        expect(res).toEqual({ name: 'amelia' });
        done();
      },
    });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71021143/exampleXHR.test.js (7.859 s)
  71021143
    ✓ should pass (37 ms)

  console.log
    { name: 'amelia' }

      at Object.onSuccess (stackoverflow/71021143/exampleXHR.test.js:28:17)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 exampleXHR.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.41 s
```